# Do i need to explicitly mention has_many even after specifying belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have created models in rails using

```
rails g model User uid:integer name:string
```

and

```
rails g model Post message:string user:references
```

The above lines generated models like following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :uid
end
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :message
end
```

Now do i need to explicitly add a `has_many :posts` in the `User` model ?

also how can i make `user_id` in `Post` model `NOT NULL` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now do i need to explicitly add a has_many :posts in the User model ?

Yes if you want to find posts of user User.firs.posts

> also how can i make user_id in Post model NOT NULL ?

Add migration

```
change_column :posts, :user, :integer, :null => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the `has_many :posts` unless you're going to make queries like `current_user.posts`. Rails uses associations to tie in queries like that.

In order to make sure user_id is not null you can do one or both.

1. Add validation in your model like so:

`validates :user_id, :presence => true`

1. Add a database contraint to make it so that the database also does not allow null values for that

`t.integer "user_id",   :null => false`

The latter will make the database consistent by not allowing you to insert values null through SQL queries.